# How can I solve system.numerics.vector error while using CSharpmath.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
Warning     Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Numerics.Vectors" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
    "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was chosen because it was primary and "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was not.
    References which depend on "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll].
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll".
            System.Numerics.Vectors
    References which depend on "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [].
        C:\Users\vizid\.nuget\packages\csharpmath.rendering\0.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\CSharpMath.Rendering.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\vizid\.nuget\packages\csharpmath.rendering\0.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\CSharpMath.Rendering.dll".
            C:\Users\vizid\.nuget\packages\csharpmath.rendering\0.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\CSharpMath.Rendering.dll
            C:\Users\vizid\.nuget\packages\csharpmath.forms\0.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\CSharpMath.Forms.dll
            C:\Users\vizid\.nuget\packages\csharpmath.skiasharp\0.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\CSharpMath.SkiaSharp.dll   Test.Android
```

Hello, I have this warning while using CSharpMath 0.5.1 and it is not working, I used to use 0.3.0 but I need to update to 0.5.1 because a lot of issues have been fixed, but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: What error?  You've only mentioned a warning, not an error.  And "not working" is not a useful description of the problem

Comment: CSharpmath let's you use LaTeX in your app, but using 0.5.1 the LaTeX won't work, using 0.3.0 works and this error is not there, so I am assuming this error causes it not working

Comment: You can recheck if you have installed `System.Numerics.Vectors` nuget with different version in your project. If so, try to reinstall it.

Comment: In Visual Studio you can open, via right click on your solution in "solution explorer" -> "Manage Nuget Packages for Solution" and check if you have some more hints. I would assume you have a "direct" and an "indirect" reference to nuget paackage "System.Numerics.Vectors" and the are refereing different versions.

Comment: I made a new xamarin.forms project and I just added the CSharpMath library, If I add the system.numerics.vector via nuget package the issue still remains

Comment: I created a new xamarin.forms project and  added  `CSharpMath.Forms`  nuget with vertion 0.5.1 and `system.numerics.vector` nuget with version 4.5.0, but I couldn't reproduce this problem.  Could you please post a demo so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?